# warranty on tablets/ipads bought from Malaysia

Tags: iphone, warranty

My friend in Malaysia is visiting me in Australia and is bringing me a Apple 64gb tablet as a gift. As I have been given conflicting answers to this question; Will the warranty on the Apple tablet be honoured in Sydney Australia or is it only the iPad that is not under warranty in Australia.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the iPad is in warranty, only iPhones have a country specific warranty, rest all Apple products have international warranty.

**UPDATE**
Apple has launched international warranty for iPhones. Details can be checked [here](http://indianexpress.com/article/technology/iphone-8/apple-international-warranty-for-iphones-why-it-is-a-good-idea-to-buy-iphone-x-from-the-us-now-4907026/).

Comment: Could you please provide a source for that information? (about the international warranty) thanks.

Comment: As I travel a lot, I have personally dealt with warranty issues with my iPad, iPod and iPhone, for which only the warranty on my iPhone was not support, rest all the other products were covered, thus on asking the Apple Care Representative I was told that only iPhones have a country specific warranty.